# How to fix search result "Access denied You are not authorized to access this page"

Tags: search

How to fix search result "Access denied You are not authorized to access this page"?
Have tried to change permissions and search module configuration, nothing helps...

Comment: What do you mean by fixing it? Do you mean you want to give access to users or you want to display a better error message or what?

Answer (score 2):

In admin/people/permissions, make sure that the roles that should be allowed to search are checked. Under the *Search* heading, look for the *Use search* permission. If anonymous users need this permission, check the box next to *Anonymous User*.
Next, clear your Drupal cache.

If you use Drush, you can use the following command.

```
drush cc all
```

There are several other ways to [clear your cache](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/clearing-rebuilding-cache) as well.

Lastly, you can try rebuilding your permissions at admin/reports/status/rebuild.